# How do I get scribble to make -- be two short dashes rather than one long dash?

Tags: documentation, racket, scribble

In scribble, when I put two dashes (or even three dashes) together, such as `--`, it comes out as one long dash. How can I make scribble keep them as two short dashes, such as in [this documentation page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/docs.html?q=raco%20doc)?

My ultimate goal is to be able to turn them into flags for a command, such as `-h` and `--`.

[`verbatim`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html?q=verbatim#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._verbatim%29%29) Does keep the dashes separate, but it also changes the font, and makes a new paragraph, which I don't want.

Comment: Ironic that the two dashes in the title have been turned into one long dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only goal is to add documentation for command line flags such as `-h` and `--`, then you can use the commands:

- [`DFlag`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-strings.html?q=DFlag#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._.D.Flag%29%29)
- [`Flag`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-strings.html?q=flag#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._.Flag%29%29)

The first will give you `--` for longer flags, and the second will give you `-` for shorter flags. They will also change the font to match the terminal typeface for the docs.